# Fragment in FragmentViewPager does not respond while swiping between Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got Drawer Layout that has four Fragments

One of it is Fragment is called Debtors. Debtors has FragmentViewPager that should return FragmentDebtorsForMe or FragmentDebtorsMeToOther.

The way I create CategoryAdapterDebtors in Debtors.class (Debtors extends Fragment)

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.debtors_viewpager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.debtors_tabs);

    CategoryAdapterDebtors categoryAdapterDebtors = new CategoryAdapterDebtors
            (getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(categoryAdapterDebtors);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

CategoryAdapterDebtors that extends FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapterDebtors extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public CategoryAdapterDebtors(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position==0)
        return new FragmentDebtorsForMe();
    if(position==1)
        return new FragmentDebtorsMeToOther();

    return null;

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return "For me";
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return "Me to other";
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

I will paste one of two fragment that should appear in ViewPager because they have both the same problem and at the beggining those class have the same content.

```
public class FragmentDebtorsForMe extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = FragmentDebtorsForMe.class.getSimpleName();

DatabaseClients dbClients;
List<Client> listOfClients;

public FragmentDebtorsForMe() {
    Log.i(TAG, "FragmentDebtorsForMe: START");
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: start");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listOfClients = getAllClientsFromDatabase();


    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: end");
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: START");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: END");
    return rootView;

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "halo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.i(TAG, "onAttach: START");
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDetach: START");
    super.onDetach();
}

public List<Client> getAllClientsFromDatabase() {
    dbClients = new DatabaseClients(getContext());
    List<Client> clients = dbClients.getAllClient();

    for(Client c: clients)
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllClientsFromDatabase: " + c.toString());

    return clients;
}
```

}

Problem is that when I am swiping between Fragments any of my Log.i don't respond.

Other strange things is when on my Navigation Drawer I click debtors then Logs are called both from FragmentDebtorsForMe and FragmentDebtorsMeToOther but only once and no more while swiping between ViewPager.

When I create random view for example for FragmentDebtorsMeToOther it show it view properly(onCreateView work) but Log.i still doesn't work

I don't know what could cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both fragments are created at the same time, that's why you see all logs at once. This is because by default, the ViewPager preloads the next and previous pages. The slowdown you are seeing is caused by the fact that you are accessing your database on the main thread in onCreate(), instead of doing it on a background thread. The main thread must never be blocked because it is responsible for responding to UI events.